# How to get all available perl modules list

Tags: perl, module, cpan

How can i get only the list of all perl modules with short description of what they will do? So that it will help learners like me to use modules as per our need immediately, rather that searching it for long time.

Comment: Unclear. Please give us a bit more context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A list of all the modules included with Perl is in [`perldoc perlmodlib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlmodlib).

There are thousands of modules on CPAN. It's easier to [search for the module you want](https://metacpan.org/).